# Spawn point on the highest vertex of a mesh with geometry-nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to spawn a point at the highest vertex of a mesh? I want to display the height of that vertex directly above it. But currently I can't isolate the highest vertex from the rest of the mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to Chris' solution when you don't animate the highest point (it stays the same) or you're fine with a bubble (here a flag) transitioning immediately to the new highest:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to spawn just a single point :D but +1 for the cool wavy flag

Answer (score 4):

Here is a node tree which can do that:

It spawns several points and move them upwards at the highest point:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to spawn just a single point :)

Comment: i know, but i think that my gif is more interesting that way :D

Comment: both your answers answer my question perfectly. Im not sure which answer to mark as accepted t be honest :(

Comment: just give it to Markus - he has less points and he needs more ;)

Comment: You guys are awesome :)