# Move Object along a Path created using geonode

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms, path

This is part of the large feature. I created a Bezier Curve and a plane. using raycasting, I projected the curve onto a plane. The projected curve is set to be of type Path. I want to move the ojbect along the projected curve. How to do that?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you shrinkwrapped your curve is irrelevant. You can *Sample Curve* position by factor:

[image]

How you animate the factor is up to you: you could use a driver, or pass "Scene Time: seconds", you could use a map range on the seconds/frame etc.

Comment: What if the syzanne had other objects. They should move along suzanne most of the time except at few places like the wheels of the car? How to do that with this.

Comment: Will i be able to do it in the keyframe editor? Which one will take precedence?

Comment: @ph_zero you could use *Collection Info* instead of *Object Info*, like I do here with a flag: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/303333/60486

Comment: got it. what I meant was that the collection moves along the suzanne, which is good. But at some points along the curve, few items in collection except suzanne should change a little like drift. so they either spread out a little or rotate differently etc.